# Webpack ERROR - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I'm learning to build my react project using Webpack.
I already have configuration a webpack.config.js to load CSS file.

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {

  ...

  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' },
        ],
      },

     ...

    ],
  },
  
  ...

}
```

> npm run build

This problem appeared.

> ````
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:3) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are
> configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders |  * Copyright 2011-2020
> Twitter, Inc. |  * Licensed under MIT
> (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
> >  */:root{--blue:#007bff;--indigo:#6610f2;--purple:#6f42c1;--pink:#e83e8c;--red:#dc3545;
> .....  ```
> ````

I don't understand what should to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you exclude `node_modules` why you're still importing css from there which means just remove `exclude: /(node_modules)/` then would work:

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  // exclude: /(node_modules)/, // Remove this 
  use: [
    { loader: 'style-loader' },
    { loader: 'css-loader' },
  ],
},
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Reason why I used exclude node_modules because this is a copied webpack configuration from a another tutorial.

Comment: seems like node_modules are excluded as a means to make bundling more efficient? -- so there might a better fix than not excluding it